# What is the best simulation of majority utilizing $\bmod\{2,3,\dots,p\}$ gates?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, lower-bounds, big-picture, ac0

It is known $AC^0[2]$ cannot get majority function.

Is there a literature on simulation of $MAJ$ function utilizing $AC^0[2,3,\dots,p]$ gates for a finite fixed set of primes $2$ to $p=O(1)$?

What is the best we found?

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly what you're looking for, [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.4230/LIPIcs.CCC.2019.23) seems to be the most current (2019) efforts towards tight $AC^0[2]$ bounds as of yet, and provides a good summary of the difference between $AC^0$ and $AC^0[2]$ bounds.